# Windows boot manager is on both hard drives?

Tags: ssd, multi-boot

I've got two hard drives and I'm trying to have a linux drive and a windows drive.  I noticed that the boot menu will display Windows Boot Manager for both SSD's. After looking online for the cause, I tried reinstalling both OS's with the other drive disconnected (no sata, but power connected). Still, WBM is listed for both drives. What is going on?

Comment: Did you wipe the drives before reinstalling each OS?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because some UEFI is silly/bugged. As "fallback" EFI binaries (including the non- but de facto standard `bootmgfw.efi`) are registered to the UEFI by the UEFI itself. Sometimes the entries just get sticky somehow on some machines while they shouldn't.

You can try to delete the unwanted entries with `efibootmgr`, or even more "dangerously", `chattr -i` and `rm` `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/*` to "reset" as much as possible of the NVRAM of your UEFI. Note that some UEFI is really bugged that even deleting an entry can brick it (from what I heard), so no warranty here for either of the aforementioned suggestions.